# SqlException Timeout occurring instantaneously

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

During startup of an AspNetCore application, we are seeing this exception get thrown:

```
An error occurred while starting the application.
Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
Unknown location

SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__122_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)

Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Show raw exception details
SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__122_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)
System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask<TAntecedentResult, TResult>.InnerInvoke()
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref Task currentTaskSlot)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> parameterValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, bool buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync<TState, TResult>(Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync<TState, TResult>(Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor+AsyncSelectEnumerable<TSource, TResult>+AsyncSelectEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor<T>+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult>(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> accumulator, Func<TAccumulate, TResult> resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

What is interesting about this case is that the exception is thrown instantaneously - we make a request to the app, the startup code is initiated and the exception is thrown all within a second. Also, if we start a trace on the DB using SQL profiler, we are not seeing any statement being executed on the server.

If we recycle the app pool, the problem goes away. What could be causing this? My only guess is that some bad state is cached in the EF Core layer which is causing EF to throw the exception without even attempting to make a request to the DB.

Here are some relevant versions on the environment:

```
.NET Core 4.6.30411.01 X64 v4.0.0.0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.1.1-rtm-30846
Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393
```

**EDIT 1:**

The code has been requested, here is the code that throws the exception:

```
public async Task<List<OperationalMessagingQueue>> GetAllIncludeMessageAndMarketsAsNoTrackingAsync()
{
    return await DbContext.GetSet<OperationalMessagingQueue>().AsNoTracking()
        .Include(q => q.Messages)
        .ThenInclude(m => m.OperationalMessage.EcfClaimNotify.Markets)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

When the exception is thrown, the call stack always starts in the startup code, Startup.Configure(), as per this binding in UseStartup():

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Comment: `or the server is not responding.` There's no .NET Core 4.6 anyway and ASP.NET Core 2.1 is out of support. Post your actual code. It's quite likely that the code forgets to await an async operation and ends up trying to use a disposed DbContext

Comment: Those versions were copied-pasted from the web page, so I guess they must b genuine versions. I appreciate that ASP.NET core 2.1 is out of support, but this code is working on other environments, it must be something environmental - perhaps the version of .Net Core framework, or app pool recycling policies. I don't think it is related to using a disposed DbContext - I'm pretty sure you get a different error message when that happens.

Comment: Post your code. Don't make people guess. The stack trace shows a call to `System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_` and nothing more. It's quite probable your code is missing an `await`. EF Core 2.x had several significant issues, including the silent use of client-side evaluation when it couldn't generate a SQL statement.

Comment: `but this code is working on other environments` does it? Or does it seem to do so even though it loads eg an entire table in memory? .NET Core 2.1 isn't just out of support, it's beyond its End Of Life date. There's no fix for any problems you may discover. Not even security issues. EF Core 2.x specifically was barely functional. You *have* to upgrade to a supported Long Term Support version if you want to avoid such problems. The current LTS versions are 6.0 and 3.1, with 3.1 reaching EOL in December 2022

Comment: If this is a random happened issue? If not, can you offer the line-code where the issue happened?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your interest...I've been busy on other things but this problem has reared its head again, this time in a client production environment. I have pasted in the method containing the line that throws the exception. Once the app is in this state, it throws this exception - instantly - upon every request made to the app. It is throwing the exception inside the startup code. The code does work in other environments, yes, we have tested it - as long as the DB doesn't timeout on first attempt to start the app, the code runs fine upon every request